# Databinding a collection to labels and dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm try to create a `System.Windows.Window` to allow a user to map user-inputted food to a pre-selected number of categories.  For example, the user types in "apple" and then selects Fruit from a dropdown, then types in "banana" and selects Fruit, then types in "carrot" and selects Vegetable, etc (a one-to-many mapping).  For this I believe I need a textbox and a dropdown, contained a ListView or GridView.

I want to do DataBinding to make this easier, but since I'm new to WPF, even simple stuff is hard (let alone creating complex situations like I've described).  To make things more complicated, the Window needs to be able to load the user's previous selections.  I assume I need to pass into the Window constructor two things, to be made public properties (for access for DataBinding):

1. A List of all possible categories to fill the category dropdown.  For example,

   ```
   this.Category = new List<string>{ "Fruit", "Vegetable", "Grain" };
   ```
2. A Dictionary of previous selections (mapping a "food" string to one of the categories).  In this example,

   ```
   this.PriorSelections = new Dictionary< string, string >() { {"banana", "fruit"} };
   ```

How can I achieve this in WPF using databinding in .NET 3.0?  The GridViewColumn declarations is where I'm stuck the most right now, but all other insight is greatly welcome.  If GridView or ListView is the incorrect container, please let me know if another container would be best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Little example for you which uses a DataGrid that can be filled by the user:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:TestWpfProject="clr-namespace:TestWpfProject"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="213" Width="404"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        >
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Resources>
        <TestWpfProject:Categories x:Key="comboItems"/>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="100" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn MinWidth="100" Header="Type" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList, Source={StaticResource comboItems}}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>    
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please note the Datacontext is set to self (the MainWindow) => `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

In your code you must provide bindable objects like this:

```
namespace TestWpfProject
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public class Fruit
    {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>();
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits
    {
      get; set; 
    }
  }

  public class Categories
  {
    public List<string> CategoryList { get; set; }
    public Categories()
    {
      CategoryList = new List<string>() { "fruit", "vegetable", "grain" };
    }
  }
}
```

Data will be stored in the Fruits observable list object.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a nearly-perfect answer (and I may still mark it as such, since I didn't mention this criteria at first either), but I have to do this in .NET 3.0 - so sorry!  I really appreciate you mocking this up for me!